# Getting value from EditText within an AlertDialog Builder

Tags: java, android

Right, I know there's alot of similar questions. I've researched on stackoverflow as well as on the internet about this but still stumped.

This code is in a fragment.

```
...
private Context context = getActivity();

public void Dialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(mView);

    EditText a = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.a);
    EditText b = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.b);
    EditText c = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.c);

    //a.setText("abc");
    //b.setText("xyz");
    //c.setText("123");

    strA = a.getText().toString();
    strB = b.getText().toString();
    final String strC = c.getText().toString();
}
```

This should be a typical approach to getting the view of the inflated layout and using it to access the elements inside the view, but it's not working no matter what I tried, I just could not get strA, strB and strC values using getText().toString().

```
    //a.setText("abc");
    //b.setText("xyz");
    //c.setText("123");
```

But, if I uncomment the above 3 lines, the values get sent across. And I can receive them inside strA, strB, strC. Why is this so? I don't get it at all.

Any help greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: There is no action to get strings from EditTexts. You should define a button on your dialog. than you can get the strings via button.onclicklistener...

Comment: Yes thank you for the advice. I completely overlooked that. Indeed I have an onClickListener below this code and I was straightaway checking the values. Amateur/tired mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get values at the time you initialize the dialog. you need to get values after an action, like a button click

```
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
     strA = a.getText().toString();
     strB = b.getText().toString();
  }
});
```

Have a look at this [display textview in alert dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191562/display-textview-in-alert-dialog)

Comment: Yes thank you very much! I completely overlooked that I should be getting the values in onClick. Thanks! I will mark your answer as correct as you gave an example. Thank you! Can't believe I made such a mistake, tired is an excuse.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're checking the values of the EditTexts as soon as they're created. Which of course the value is going to be null every time since your user hasn't had time to type anything. I think you need a SubmitButton or something similar that checks the EditTexts in its onClickListener. Though I'll admit I've never inflated a view into an alert dialog.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I actually have an onClickListener to an OK button on the dialogbox but I completely overlooked that and thus made an amateur mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The layout is not yet initiated when you are trying to set the values, you need to call `AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();` and then `alertDialog.show();` or just `alertDialogBuilder.show()` before you can edit the textView content.

Comment: Yes indeed, I have the create/show after this chunk of code. I completely forgot about the OK button part. My mistake! Thanks!

Comment: Using OK button is not a must, once the dialog is shown using show method, you can get or set values to any views inside the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. 
MyDialogue is your Activity name.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyDialogue.this);

                // Get the layout inflater
                LayoutInflater inflater = MyDialogue.this.getLayoutInflater();

                // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
                // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
                View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(mView);

                final EditText a = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.a);
                final EditText b = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.b);
                final EditText c = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.c);

                a.setText("abc");
                b.setText("xyz");
                c.setText("123");

                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            final String strA = a.getText().toString();
                            final String strB = b.getText().toString();
                            final String strC = c.getText().toString();
                            Log.e("tag", strA + "  " + strB + "  " + strC );
                      }
                    });
                alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your example! It's indeed what I missed out, thank you thank you!